# @nestjs/jwt - Cannot read property 'challenge' of undefined

Tags: jwt, nestjs

I use `jwt` tokens in my `nestjs` app but when I run my project and call a controller with `@UseGuards(AuthGuard())` decorator, the app debug return the following error:

```
Cannot read property 'challenge' of undefined
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Instead of this line:

```
@UseGuards(AuthGuard())
```

Use this one:

```
@UseGuards(AuthGuard('jwt'))
```

Answer (score 6):

you have to import `PassportModule` as

```
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([UserRepository]),
    HttpModule,
    ConfigModule,
    PassportModule.register({ defaultStrategy: 'jwt' }),
  ],
```

into **every** module where you want to use default strategy.